# Conver Java and Json into String for android app translation

Tags: java, android, json, translation

I have a Java Class on android with these Strings and I want to translate them into other languages:

```
String s = "<b>Shipping Date:</b>" + shipping_date.toString();
loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));

String t = "<b>Time:</b>" + shipping_time.toString();
loadtime.setText(Html.fromHtml(t));

String u = "<b>c.getString(shipping_address)</b>" + shipping_address_address.toString();
loadplace.setText(Html.fromHtml(u));

String v = "<b>Description:</b>" + description.toString();
txtdesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(v));

String w = "<b>Weight:</b>" + weight.toString() + " KG";
txtweight.setText(Html.fromHtml(w));

String x = "<b>Destination Date:</b>" + destination_date.toString();
txtdestdate.setText(Html.fromHtml(x));

String y = "<b>Time:</b>" + destination_time.toString();
txtdesttime.setText(Html.fromHtml(y));

String z = "<b>Destination Address:</b>" + destination_address_address.toString();
txtdestplace.setText(Html.fromHtml(z));
```

Could someone please help me?

Thanks,

Nico

Comment: `java != javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract your text to a strings.xml resource file use placeholders and escape html tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="shipping_date">"&lt;b>Shipping Date: &lt;/b>  %1$s"</string>
    </resources>
```

In your code you can call

```
String s= getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_date, shipping_date.toString());
loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

Then you can create different strings.xml files for different languages

More infos:

[String files for different languages](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

[String resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)